# RMI application does not work in LAN

Tags: java, rmi

I have a simple RMI application, when I tried to run it in the LAN it doesn't working, my classes are as follows,

```
public interface HelloInterface extends Remote {

    public String say() throws RemoteException;
}
```

---

```
public class Hello extends UnicastRemoteObject implements HelloInterface {

    private String message;

    public Hello(String msg) throws RemoteException {
        message = msg;
    }

    @Override
    public String say() throws RemoteException {
        return message;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class RmiServer {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        try {
            Naming.rebind("Hello", new Hello("Hello, world!"));
            System.out.println("Hello Server is ready.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Hello Server failed: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TestRMI {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        try {

            HelloInterface hello =  (HelloInterface) Naming.lookup("rmi://192.168.*.*/Hello");
            System.out.println(hello.say());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("HelloClient exception: " + e);
        }

        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

please assist me to make this app work in the LAN.

Comment: Have you read [Writing an RMI Server](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/server.html) tutorial?

Comment: Have you started the rmi registry before running your app? If you don't start it programmatically in your app, you need to start it manually from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the firewall allows you to connect? I had to turn off my firewall on the server, and the clients connecting.